# How to insert selected data from mysql with php to another table in mysql?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Hello guys i have a problem. I dont know how to insert data from php to the database, first of all, i did selects to the database to get the data. The user choose the data in the form with the options and he sends it, but the insert doesnt work. What can be the problem?

This is the file index.php

```html
    <?php
    session_start();
    if($_SESSION['userid'] == TRUE )

     {
    ?>

    <?php
     
    // Definimos nuestra zona horaria
    date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Madrid");
    include 'funciones.php';
    include 'config.php';


    // Verificamos si se ha enviado el campo con name from
    if (isset($_POST['from'])) 
    {

// Recibimos la fecha de inicio y la fecha final desde el form y la formateamos con la funcion _formatear

   $inicio = _formatear($_POST['from']);
   $final = _formatear($_POST['to']);   
   $inicio_normal =$_POST['from'];
   $final_normal = $_POST['to'];
   $cod_falta = $_POST['coid_falta'];
   $cod_alumno =$_POST['cod_alumno'];
   $cod_profesor = $_SESSION['userid'];
   $cod_ubi = $_POST['cod_emplazamiento'];
   $cod_obs = $_POST['observacion'];
     
      
 $query="INSERT INTO castigos ('start','end','inicio_normal','final_normal','cod_falta','cod_alumno','cod_profesor','cod_emplazamiento','observaciones') VALUES ('$inicio','$final','$inicio_normal','$final_normal','$cod_falta','$cod_alumno','$cod_profesor','$cod_ubi','$cod_obs')";
       
$conexion->query($query) or die ("no se ha realizado la consulta"); 
      
// Obtenemos el ultimo id insetado
$im=$conexion->query("SELECT MAX(id) AS id FROM castigos");
$row = $im->fetch_row();  
$id = trim($row[0]);

// para generar el link del evento
$link = "$base_url"."descripcion_evento.php?id=$id";

// y actualizamos su link
$query="UPDATE castigos SET url = '$link' WHERE id = $id";

// Ejecutamos nuestra sentencia sql
$conexion->query($query); 

// redireccionamos a nuestro calendario
header("Location:$base_url"); 
        }
        
      ?>
    <form action="" method="post">
         
         <label for="cbx_estado">Curso</label>
         <select class="form-control" name="cbx_estado" id="cbx_estado">
         <option value="">Seleccionar Curso</option>
         <?php 
         $query_curso = 'SELECT * FROM curso';
         $result_curso=$conexion->query($query_curso);
         while($row_curso = $result_curso->fetch_assoc()) 
         
         { ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $row_curso['cod_curso']; ?>">
          <?php echo $row_curso['curso']; ?></option>
         <?php 
         } 
         ?>
         </select>
         
         
        
         <br />
         <label for="cbx_alumnos">Alumno</label>
         <select class="form-control" name="cbx_alumnos" id="cbx_alumnos"></select>
           
           </br>   

          
         
         <label for="cod_falta">Tipo de falta</label>
                        <select class="form-control" name="cod_falta" id="cod_falta">    
           <option value="">Seleccionar falta</option>
          <?php 
           $query_falta = 'SELECT * FROM faltas';
           $result_falta = $conexion->query($query_falta); 
           while ( $row_falta = $result_falta->fetch_array() )    
          {
          ?>  
           <option value=" <?php echo $row_falta['cod_falta']  ?> " >
           <?php echo $row_falta['falta']; ?>
           </option>    
          
          <?php
          }    
          ?>  
          
         </select>
           
           </br>   

          <label for="cod_emplazamiento">Ubicación del castigo </label>
                        <select class="form-control" name="cod_emplazamiento" id="cod_emplazamiento">    
           <option value="">Seleccionar ubicación</option>
          <?php 
           $query_ubi = 'SELECT * FROM emplazamiento_castigos';
           $result_ubi = $conexion->query($query_ubi); 
           while ( $row_ubi = $result_ubi->fetch_array() )    
          {
          ?>  
           <option value=" <?php echo $row_ubi['cod_emplazamiento']  ?> " >
           <?php echo $row_ubi['emplazamiento']; ?>
           </option>    
          
          <?php
          }    
          ?>        
         </select>
         
      
         <br>
      
                        <label for="from">Inicio de castigo</label>
                          <div class='input-group date' name='from' id='from'>
                        <input type='text' class="form-control" readonly />
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                        </span>
                    </div>

                        <br>

                        <label for="to">Final de castigo</label>
                          <div class='input-group date' name='to' id='to'>
                        <input type='text' class="form-control" readonly />
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                        </span>
                    </div>

                        <br>

                        <label for="observacion">Tarea y observaciones</label>
                        <textarea id="observacion" name="observacion" class="form-control" rows="1"></textarea>
     
          </div>
       
     <script type="text/javascript">
     
            $(function () {
                $('#from').datetimepicker({
               
          format: 'MM/DD/YYYY', 
        maxViewMode: 0,
        language: 'es',
        daysOfWeekDisabled: '0,6',
        todayHighlight: true,    
                    minDate: new Date(1, 1, 2017),
        pickTime: false
       
                });
                $('#to').datetimepicker({
                   
        format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
        maxViewMode: 0,
        language: 'es',
        daysOfWeekDisabled: '0,6',
        todayHighlight: true,
                    minDate: new Date(1, 1, 2017),
        pickTime: false
          });
       
      });
      </script>
      
          <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Cancelar</button>
          <input type="Submit" name="enviar" value="Agregar" class="btn btn-success" >
            
     
            </form>

<?php
 } else {
  header("Location: index_log.php");
 }
  ?>
```

My table name castigos.php

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
$query="INSERT INTO castigos (start,end,inicio_normal,final_normal,cod_falta,cod_alumno,cod_profesor,cod_emplazamiento,observaciones) VALUES ('$inicio','$final','$inicio_normal','$final_normal','$cod_falta','$cod_alumno','$cod_profesor','$cod_ubi','$cod_obs')";

if ($conexion->query($query) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record Successfully<br>";
}       
else
{
    echo "Error: " . $query. "<br>" . $con->error;
}
```